# Session numbers pulled from API dont match the numbers displayed in the Google Analytics Report

Tags: google-analytics

For my recent project, i m trying to develop a brand new report for google analytics using the Sessions data over a period of time.
When I compare the numbers that I get from https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/  and check the report that we have created in analytics.google.com the numbers for sessions are off. They dont match exactly. They are off by like 1%. What might be the reason for this.

Can someone please help me here?
I can give more details if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Is either report getting  sampled?

Comment: No. No sampling at all. I have

Comment: This has been asked a couple of times, and while there is no canonical answer the best hypothesis so far is that this a problem with the timeframe - apparently the API calculates the session rollover a little different than the interface and thus returns slightly different results.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above , one more thing I noticed
This happens only When I add Segment filter to be specific. Without the segments the numbers for all users look good.

Answer (score 0):

Had a call with Google Analytics support. They say that there isnt actual support for the Rest Api code and the Front End report from Google Analytics has built in Logic to filter out certain personal information like age related, sex, etc. which is not there in the Rest Api when it pulls in data.

So this is the reason why the numbers are off by 1% all the time.

Hope this helps
Thanks